# Relative hazard ratio curve?

Tags: r, data-visualization, splines, hazard

I have been trying to plot hazard ratio spline curves for two groups (treatment/nontreatment), showing HR varying over the continuous variable Age, but using the nontreatment group as the reference (HR = 1), something that I have seen quite often in large medical studies. See for instance figure 2 in [this](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa1613792#iid=f02) publication, or this curve: [image: curve1]
from [this](https://academic.oup.com/eurheartj/article/34/46/3547/531706?searchresult=1) publication.

It probably isn´t very complicated, but I can´t find out how to do it. Not even [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/splines.pdf) very nice tutorial shows how to do it.

Terry Therneaus tutorial includes this example:

```
library(survival)
library(splines)
nfit3 <- coxph(Surv(futime, death) ~ sex * ns(age, df=3), flchain)
pdata <- expand.grid(age= 50:99, sex=c("F", "M"))
ypred <- predict(nfit3, newdata=pdata, se=TRUE)
yy <- ypred$fit + outer(ypred$se, c(0, -1.96, 1.96), '*')
matplot(50:99, exp(matrix(yy, ncol=6)), type='l', lty=c(1,1,2,2,2,2),
    lwd=2, col=1:2, log='y',
    xlab="Age", ylab="Relative risk")
legend(55, 20, c("Female", "Male"), lty=1, lwd=2, col=1:2, bty='n')
abline(h=1)
```

which produces this curve:
[image: curve]

Do anyone out there know how to modify the code, or if there are any other (simpler) methods to produce the curve I am looking for?